# Control 2 servo motors with 2 buttons Arduino

Tags: arduino, servo

I'm working on another school project where I'm trying to make an obstacle course (model size). For this project I'm using 2 servo motors, which I want to control with 2 different buttons. So 1 button is connected to 1 servo motor and the other one is connected to the other servo. I'm actually struggling to get both buttons to work with the servo motors.

When I attach 1 button and 1 servo motor everything works exactly the way I want. I press the button, the servo motor moves 90 degrees and after 5 seconds it moves back.

The code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;

const int servoPin = D8;  // Servo pin
const int buttonPin = D7;  // Pushbutton pin

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(servoPin);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}//setup

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) {
    myservo.write(180);
    delay(50);  // waits 50ms to reach the position
    delay(15000);//15 seconden wachten
    myservo.write(0);
    delay(50);  // waits 50ms to reach the position
  }
}//loop
```

However I read on a forum that when you want to use more then one servo motor, you have to write the code differently. You have to include servo motors like this:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservoa, myservob;
```

When I changed the code everything stopped working and I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong here. I want the servo motors to work AT THE SAME TIME, with 2 different buttons.

The new code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservoa, myservob;

const int servoPin1 = D8;  // Servo pin
const int servoPin2 = D6;  // Servo pin 
const int buttonPin1 = D7; // Pushbutton pin
const int buttonPin2 = D5; // Pushbutton pin

void setup() {
  myservoa.attach(servoPin1);
  myservob.attach(servoPin2);
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
}//setup

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin1) == HIGH) {
    myservoa.write(90);
    delay(50);  // waits 50ms to reach the position
    delay(5000);// 5 seconden wachten
    myservoa.write(0);
    delay(50);  // waits 50ms to reach the position
  }
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin2) == HIGH) {
    myservob.write(90);
    delay(50);  // waits 50ms to reach the position
    delay(5000);// 5 seconden wachten
    myservob.write(0);
    delay(50);  // waits 50ms to reach the position
  }
}//loop
```

I hope somebody can help me out!

---

EDIT:

So i found out that 2 servo motors actually was to much for my NodeMCU. The code in the comments worked fine tho! Now I'm trying to combine the servo motor with a small vibration motor. The 2 sensors work well together but I can't get the vibration motor to work properly.

I want the vibration motor to vibrate for 5 seconds after I pressed the button. After 5 seconds it has to stop automatically. With the code the vibration motor only vibrates when I press the button. When the button isn't pressed, the vibration motor stops directly.

Code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;

const int servoPin = D8;  // Servo pin
const int vibratiePin = D3;  // Servo pin
const int buttonPin1 = D6;  // Pushbutton pin
const int buttonPin2 = D5;  // Pushbutton Pin

unsigned long stopA = 0;
unsigned long stopB = 0;

bool controlA = false;
bool controlB = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  myservo.attach(servoPin);
  pinMode(vibratiePin, OUTPUT);

}//setup

void loop() {

    unsigned long now = millis();

    if(controlA && stopA < now) {
        myservo.write(0);
        controlA = false;
    } else if (!controlA && digitalRead(buttonPin1) == HIGH) {
        controlA = true;
        myservo.write(90);
        stopA = millis() + 5000;
    }

        if(controlB && stopB < now) {
        digitalWrite(vibratiePin, LOW);
        controlB = false;
        stopB = millis() + 5000;
       } else if  (!controlB && digitalRead(buttonPin2) == HIGH) {
        controlB = true;
        digitalWrite(vibratiePin, HIGH); 
}

stopB = now;

}
```

I hope somebody can see the problem here because I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are sleeping the code at each on if statement:

```
if (digitalRead(buttonPin1) == HIGH) {
    ...
    delay(5000);// the code is blocked for 5 seconds here
    ...
}
```

So if the buttonPin1 is HIGH the code after that block will run just after 5100 milliseconds after (at least).

Indeed you shouldn't use longs delays like that inside the loop. The reason is what you see: while the code is stopped the motors are still running and it is a real dangerous scenario for real applications.

The solution is: don't sleep! There are several ways to do it. One of them is use a program variable to control the state of each of motors and another one to set the time limit to run the motor:

```
unsigned long stopA = 0;
unsigned long stopB = 0;

bool controlA = false;
bool controlB = false;

void loop() {

    unsigned long now = mills();

    if(controlA && stopA < now) {
        myservoa.write(0);
        controlA = false;
    } else if (!controlA && digitalRead(buttonPin1) == HIGH) {
        controlA = true;
        myservoa.write(90);
        stopA = mills() + 5050;
    }

    //similar to motor b
    //...
}
```

This way the code never be blocked into a sleeping command and loop can perform other actions while each motor is running.

Comment: So the code works but I'm running to another problem right now. I edited my question maybe you can help me!

Comment: In that case if you have a different problem you should ask in a different question